# PlayFramework (2.5.x) doesn't bind data from form returning Ojbect with null fields

Tags: java, forms, playframework

The problem is to bind data from form (or from Map of parameters) to actual Form object. 
I have added some `println` just for testing purposes. Here is code for Controller class.

```
package controllers;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import models.Product;
import play.data.Form;
import play.data.FormFactory;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import views.html.products.list;
import views.html.products.details;

public class Products extends Controller {

@Inject
public Products(FormFactory formFactory) {
    productForm =  formFactory.form(Product.class);
  }

private static Form<Product> productForm;

public  Result list(){
    List<Product> products = Product.findAll();
    return ok(list.render(products));
}
public  Result newProduct(){
    return ok(details.render(productForm));
}
public  Result save(){
    Form<Product> filledForm=productForm.fill(new Product("0000","0000","0000"));
    Form<Product> boundForm=productForm.bindFromRequest();
    final Product product =(Product) boundForm.get();
    System.out.println(">>Bound ean form data: "+boundForm.field("ean").value()+"->Product from bound form: "+boundForm.get());
    System.out.println(">>Filled ean form data: "+filledForm.field("ean").value()+"->Product from filled form: "+filledForm.get());
    //product.save();
    flash("success",String.format("Successfully added product %s", product));
    return redirect(routes.Products.list());
}

}
```

Here for the purpose of simplicity `class Product` is just of three public fields:

```
package models;


public class Product {


    public String ean;
    public String name;
    public String description;

    public Product() {}

    public Product(String ean, String name, String description) {
        this.ean = ean;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s - %s", ean, name);
    }


}
```

And here is Play template( without `main` wrapper template that take care of `<head> <body>` stuff)

```
@(productForm: Form[Product])
@import helper._

@main("Product form") {
<div class="main">
<h1>Product form</h1>
@helper.form(action = routes.Products.save(),'_class -> "form-group") {
<fieldset>
    <legend>Product (@productForm("name").valueOr("New"))</legend>
    @helper.inputText(productForm("ean"), '_label -> "EAN",'_class->"input")
    @helper.inputText(productForm("name"),'_label -> "Name",'_class->"input")
    @helper.textarea(productForm("description"), '_label -> "Description",'_class->"input")
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="@routes.Products.index()">Cancel</a>
}
```

}

Everything rides nice and smooth except that I get Product object with null fields, but `field(fieldName).value()` or `data()` return correct data. 
Looks like Form behaves as DynamicForm. 
Strange things starting to happen when I use `bind(Map<String,String>)` instead of `bindFromRequest()` - same result both. And resul from console is (i have used testEAN filling the form "ean" field)

```
    >>Bound ean form data: testEAN->Product from bound form: null - null
    >>Filled ean form data: null->Product from filled form: 0000 - 0000
```

Comment: The question is not very clear here.

Comment: The question is: why `Form<Product> boundForm=productForm.bindFromRequest();` doesn't bind to `Product` fields in `Form <Product> boundForm` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need to add property accessors/mutators (`getXXX/setXXX`) in `Product class`. That is crucial point

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the type of the form

```
Form<Product> boundForm = factoryForm.form(Product.class).bindFromRequest();
Product product = boundForm.get();
```

If you do not provide the type of the object you are biding how play will infer the fields and properties?!

Comment: I already have `Form<Product> productForm` that is created in constructor of controller via injecting FormFactory (as described in documentation and in book on PlayFramework) . According to docs `bind(...)` or `bindFromRequest()` returns a new form with binded parameters.

Comment: However, using your method I have same results.